# Inconsistent results from active-record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

This is my `Person` model which has the following query in a method:

```
def get_uniq_person_ids
    uniq_person_ids = select('person_id').where(:state => '1').uniq
    uniq_person_ids
end
```

My Test is as follows:

```
def test_uniqueness
    Person.delete_all
    assert_equal(0, Person.count)

    # ..... Adding 8 rows to the database with 2 unique person_id.....

    pids = Person.get_uniq_person_ids
    assert_equal(pids.size, 2)    
end
```

Test fails with the following:

> Failure:
>     <8> expected but was
>     <2>.

There are 8 rows but only 2 unique person_id in the table.

This is what I tried:

- `puts pids` before assert. It prints only 2 objects. Test fails with the above message.
- `binding.pry` right before the query. Size is 2 which is expected and the test passes this time.

> Why is the result so inconsistent? Is it a timing issue?

Note: I am using sqlite as my database.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to test anything about wiping "all the data" from the DB; if you need to wipe it, wipe it. That begs the question why you're doing it manually, though. Without knowing more about how your DB is being seeded in the test environment it's tough to say. It's almost certainly not "timing" if you're in the test environment.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am wiping all the data from my test environment db so that the data I am inserting is the only data available and the counts are predictable. That is just a pre-test setup of the db.

Comment: Right, got that; I'm asking why you're wiping data manually--there are known Rails mechanisms for wiping the database. FYI, the expected value comes first in the arg list. Again, hard to say without more info. If your tests are "normal" they're running in a random order, too, meaning there could be data leftover from previous tests since you're not cleaning the database programmatically between runs.

Comment: @DaveNewton Edited my test, I am not manually deleting anything. I just didn't show that part of the code where I wipe out the database thinking it would be unnecessary.

Comment: You're not manually deleting anything, but have code that wipes out the DB? That's... confusing. (And you've now shown where you delete things manually.) Anyway. How are you adding the rows?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am adding rows by creating a hash(named hsh) for each person with the desired column values, and then doing a `Person.create(hsh)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I am not sure what the actual issue was but the following solved it:

```
def get_uniq_person_ids
    uniq_person_ids = select('person_id').where(:state => '1').uniq
    uniq_person_ids = uniq_person_ids.map(&:person_id)
    uniq_person_ids
end
```

I added the line `uniq_person_ids = uniq_person_ids.map(&:person_id)` to create the array of person_ids.

Comment: Probably something to do with how equality is being determined in the objects, or what the objects actually contained. You made it difficult for people to help by not showing the data before or after the inserts and queries.